# Can you package an Adobe AIR app as UWP using Project Centennial?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, uwp, desktop-bridge

I'm trying to complete a proof-of-concept, but I have hit a snag. With Adobe AIR able to support iOS and Android, I wanted to see if I could use the Project Centennial workflow to convert an Adobe AIR .exe installer, into a UWP app for x86 Windows 10.

I have been able to follow the [directions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter) for the latest version (0.1.24) and have been able to get the conversion started:

> .\DesktopAppConverter.ps1 -Installer '..\AIR2UWP Example\AIR2UWP.exe'
>   -InstallerArguments "-silent" -Destination C:\ -PackageName "MyApp" -Version 0.0.0.1 -MakeAppx -Verbose -Publisher "CN=dougwinnie"

But when I use this, I get the following error:

> C:\Users\dougw\Desktop\DesktopAppConverter_new\DesktopAppConverter.ps1
>   : DesktopAppConverter : error 'E_BAD_INSTALLER_EXIT_CODE': Installer
>   returned '10' when valid exit codes were '0' At line:1 char:1
>   + .\DesktopAppConverter.ps1 -Installer '..\AIR2UWP Example\AIR2UWP.exe' ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,DesktopAppConverter.ps1

It seems that there is an installer error, but I can't seem to find any references to an AIR installer code 10 to help me troubleshoot further.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that there is an installer error, but I can't seem to find any references to an AIR installer code 10 to help me troubleshoot further

It’s up to the developer who owns the AIR platform to understand what is and is not a valid exit code for **their setup technology**(Adobe Air)

> Can you package an Adobe AIR app as UWP using Project Centennial

Air apps might not be a good candidate as the Adobe air platform works and looks like ClickOnce. Specifically, the Air platform installs an auto-update service that provides an API for the Air app to check to see if updates are available.  If you disable/remove that service, it’s very likely that no Air app will function as expected as the RPC call will likely fail.

In order to let Air apps works, we'd have to get Adobe to update the Air platform to be compatible with Centennial/UWP.